# SQL distinct box results

Tags: sql

Not sure how to write this out in words

```
Column A.       Col. B.           Col. C
123456.           Xxx.               Abbd
123456.           Yyy.               Bbbd
765432.           Xxx.               1234
765432.           Yyy.                5167
987654.           Zzz.                Abcd
987654.           Yyy.                Dbca
```

Distinct col. A  when B is xxx return col.A and col. B and C where B is Yyy

```
Results
123456. Yyy.   Bbbd
765432.  Yyy.  5167
```

But not return

```
987654 yyy dbca
```

Comment: Use words.  It'll help you understand where you're stuck, and give us a better foothold to help you with.

Comment: what?, can you explain with more details what you want?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so you need to `JOIN` against the same table, where one side returns `Column A` where `B` = `Xxx.`. Using those, get the rows having `B = Yyy.`  `987654` won't be returned because it has no rows where `ColB = 'Xxx.'`

```
SELECT
  main.ColumnA,
  main.ColB,
  main.ColC
FROM 
  yourtable main
  /* Join a second instance of the table which will be limited by ColB = Xxx */
  JOIN yourtable xids ON main.ColumnA = xids.ColumnA
WHERE
  /* And limit the main instance to ColB = Yyy */
  main.ColB = 'Yyy.'
  AND xids.ColB = 'Xxx.'
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b65d0/3

Comment: How I earth did you get that from the question? :)

Comment: @bluefeet I didn't get it from the question, which is nearly nonsense, but from the sample result.

Comment: @bluefeet But I've also developed a strong fluency in the n00bish language since hanging around here...